# Regarding C# Syntax with : and proceeding arguments in class declaration. Online converters failing to convert

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm running through a tutorial on WCF. Unfortunately, most all tutorials regarding WCF are in C# and I'm not too familiar with C# syntax; most all of my experience is in VB. I've gotten through it so far, but I ran into a bit of a snag. I think that the `:` is the equivalent of `Inherits` or `Implements` ? However I'm not sure what it means when there are two comma seperated things after a `:` in a class declaration. Here's the code in C#:

```cs
Public class MyProxy : ClientBase<InterfaceDom>, InterfaceDom
{
    Public int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return base.Channel.Add(num1, num2);
    }
}
```

When I try run it through some of the online converters the converters error out with something about EOF expected. I was hoping someone could let me know what I need to change with my VB code to make it do the same thing as the C# code above.

```vb
Public Class MyProxy
    Implements ClientBase(of InterfaceDom), InterfaceDom 'Errors out on this line
    Public Function add(ByVal num1 as Integer, ByVal num2 as Integer) as Integer
        Return MyBase.Channel.Add(num1, num2)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: As far as i know, in c# you can implement multiple interfaces, which is done with that comma separated list

Comment: In VB.NET, you don't implement multiple interfaces using a comma. You do it on a separate line. Like underneath the class name, you put `Implements ClientBase(Of InterfaceDom)` then on the next line, you put `Implements InterfaceDom`

Comment: @Icemanind Is it not `Inherits` for ClientBase instead of `implements`?

Comment: It's possible that the code converters you're using are producing errors because the name `InterfaceDom` doesn't conform to C# conventions for naming interfaces. Normally, interfaces don't spell out the word "interface" in their name, they just start with "I" and are Pascal cased, e.g. `IDom`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @PrestonGuillot It shouldn't matter what you call an interface, does it? Is there a reason why not keeping a normal naming convention would break something somewhere?

Comment: @JAT, you are correct it is a class and thus it requires `Inherits` I tired both `inherits` and `Implements` and received errors both ways. I choose to `Implements` in my example above because I knew that interfaces use them and one of the items was an interface. I've never tried inheriting or implementing more than one item so I thought maybe it was like `Dim` where you can do multiple items one line.

Comment: @BrandonB You're right, it shouldn't matter. I was just hazarding a guess as to why whatever tool you're using for conversion parsed the C# the way it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing ClientBase is a class, not an interface, so you need to inherit it, not implement it.

```
Public Class MyProxy
    Inherits ClientBase(of InterfaceDom)
    Implements InterfaceDom
    Public Function add(ByVal num1 as Integer, ByVal num2 as Integer) as Integer
        Return MyBase.Channel.Add(num1, num2)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You got it. Thanks for the example.